# Revert slingshot to old set up

Tags: slingshot

One of the new thing in slingshot is how every app is listed on top of eachother. My question is; can I set slingshot to list the apps the old way (next to eachother and bigger)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did since the option to use more than 5x3 grid was removed was to downgrade it to a specific version, following this guide https://hastebin.atvg-studios.com/dobamidivi.txt After a few updates in order to prevent doing the same again and agian I have locked it for updates with apt-mark, and now I'm crossing my fingers after every update will it work, but it pays the price to have a more comfortable applications list.

As far as I know the devs really like the new view with icons like on your screenshot and I believe there is no option to turn it back without downgrade.

Comment: Thanks. It works! Now I have the good old slingshot back.

Comment: You are welcome. Elementary tweaks can be the latest version if you keep the gsettings keys and you can modify the grid rows and columns by these keys using dconf Editor or a few terminal commands.

Comment: I wrote a little guide for it so I have it when needed: https://eosvisions.wordpress.com/2020/05/14/howto-change-slingshot-to-the-old-style-in-elementary-os/

Comment: Nice, but  you do not have to keep elementary tweaks to be the older version, if you use dconf editor to set the rows and columns. It is necessary only for creating the gsettings keys if they are not present but, probably there is a way to skip this with a few lines in terminal, but of course it is optional - it works this way now. I recommend you to link the source also, all of these was built and explained by a guy who compained like me in another closed on the subject github issue, and I aksed him to share his approach.

Comment: Okay will do. Thanks again.